# Image from API don't appear

Tags: javascript, html

I've retrieved some images from an API but they aren't appearing. Instead of the actual images appearing, the green and blue image icon is appearing in their places on my web page. What do I need to change/add in my code to get the images to appear?

```js
let html = [];
fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key="*"')
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {
 data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach(res => {
  html.push(`<h1>${res.title}</h1>`)
  html.push(`<p>${res.url}</p>`)
  html.push(`<p>${res.abstract}</p>`)
  html.push(`<p>${res.published_date}</p>`)
  html.push(`<img src='${res.multimedia[4]}.url'/>`) 
  })
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = html.join("")
  })
```

```html
     <html>
     <head>
        <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Top Stories</h1>
<button class="accordion">Story 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="res"></div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Story 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Story 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Story 4</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to assign src attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In HTML, images are defined with the `<img>` tag.
>
> The `<img>` tag is empty, it contains attributes only, and does not
>   have a closing tag.
>
> The `src` attribute specifies the URL (web address) of the image:

```js
let html = [];


fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
   // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
   data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach(res => {
      html.push(`<h1>${res.title}</h1>`)
      html.push(`<p>${res.url}</p>`)
      html.push(`<p>${res.abstract}</p>`)
      html.push(`<p>${res.published_date}</p>`)
      console.log(res.multimedia[4].url);
      html.push(`<img src='${res.multimedia[4].url}'/>`)
    })
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = html.join("")
})
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

You should use `res.multimedia[4].url` for src of `img`.

The `res.multimedia[4]` is still an object with lot of info. You can just use the src url from the object and use it as `img` source.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to add src to your image instead of value like this:

```
html.push(`<img src='${res.multimedia[4].url}'/>`)
```

Comment: This won't work since Multimedia is still an object in the response json

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
html.push(`<img src='${res.multimedia[4]}'/>`)
```

instead of this

```
html.push(`<image>${res.multimedia[4]}</image>`)
```

Comment: This won't work since Multimedia is still an object in the response json